# No respond(End task) error during compiling oracle forms with big size

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have a few oracle forms which their size is bigger than 10MB(initial version 6i we compile in 10g).

I didn’t have any problem for compiling them in windows XP but since my company renew our PC & we are using windows 7 sometimes when I want to compile these specific form manually a message box will pop up and force me to end task the job.

May I know anyone else have same problem? what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling it using the command-line version, `frmcmp` I think it's called. e.g.

```
frmcmp userid=xx/yy module=zz module_type=FORM batch=yes window_state=minimize parse=YES
```

Comment: I am using same command-line version. :( with oracle form there is no issue with compilation.

Comment: ok - I thought it was worth a try :) can't think of any other suggestions, apart from recompiling on another PC with WinXP.